# Get latitude longitude on Earth knowing satellite latitude, longitude, height and pointing angle

Tags: python, coordinates, transformation, satellite

Considering the Earth as a perfect sphere and knowing the position (latitude,longitude and height) of a satellite. I would like to transform the pointing angle from the satellite (defined by two angles) to latitude and longitude over the Earth surface.

I have seen that there are some packages in Python such as Pyproj that compute coordinate transformations, but I haven't managed to get something as I request.

Best regards and thank you

Comment: This link should help you: https://vvvv.org/blog/polar-spherical-and-geographic-coordinates

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, I think that in the link posted, they are dealing with a transformation of coordinates (being both of them centered in Earth's center). My transformation relates the Satellite center to the Earth's center sharing both of them the Earth's surface.

Comment: Could you draw a diagram to clarify?

Comment: This might be a good starting point for you - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20780/point-of-intersection-for-a-ray-and-earths-surface - you'll have to do some work to convert your satellite position and pointing angle(s) to ECEF.

Comment: Thanks for the piece of advice. This could help, it is a good start. I thought that there were some direct transformations (such as the ones mentioned of Pyproj) that do the work without going to intermediate steps such as ECEF